# gulp-recess doesn't change properties order

Tags: css, gulp

I try to convert my less files into css files using `gulp-less` and then use `gulp-recess` to change properties order in css files. Task `less` works properly but task `recess` doesn't work.
This is my **gulpfile.js** file

```
'use strict';


var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    path = require('path'),
    recess = require('gulp-recess');

// less
gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src(['less/style.less', 'less/fonts.less'])
    .pipe(less({
      paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

// recess
gulp.task('recess', ['less'], function () {
  return gulp.src(['css/style.css', 'css/fonts.css'])
    .pipe(recess())
    .pipe(recess.reporter())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

// watch
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('less/*.less', ['less']),
  gulp.watch('css/*.css', ['recess']);
});

// default
gulp.task('default', ['less', 'recess', 'watch']);
```

Errors in Node.js console 
[image]

What's wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[gulp-recess](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-recess) won't reorder your css properties, its purpose is to 'lint' your css/less files - checks for syntax errors so you can fix there warnings/errors yourself in the source files.